# How to display growl message in left side of layout screen

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In my project there is a requirement that when we change language from Engish to Arabic all layout will be displayed in  right to left position.So when i changed that all the components  dispalyed right to left except growl messages.

I want to display growl message in left side of layout screen, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Just use CSS? `html[dir=rtl] .growl { ... }` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default css for .ui-growl class is :

```
.ui-growl {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 301px;
}
```

You can achieve growl on left by applying following css for .ui-growl class:

```
 .ui-growl {
        left: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 20px;
        width: 301px;
    }
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks for reply,where should i add this css reference in this code <p:growl  id="msgs" autoUpdate="true" display="icon" ></p:growl>

Comment: can you please try  `<p:growl id="msgs" style="left:20px;" autoUpdate="true" display="icon" ></p:growl>`

Comment: its working fine but when i add this thing in common layout of my page then its not working...

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: have a look on this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337644/why-growl-message-not-dispalying-left-side-of-screen-using-common-layout